# Shorten URLs with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using wordpress, I have already my url shortened to this **domain.com/(article)/image-(image-slug)**

where (article) and (image-slug) are variables.
Note that the paranthesis are here only to show what are the variables.

I want to end up whith this form of url **domain.com/(image-slug)** using htaccess file.

Comment: I know this can sound annoying if you've spent 2 days on it, but we need to know what you've tried. It should be as simple as deleting the `(acticle)/image-` part of the `.htaccess`.

Comment: You don't want to do this in the WordPress settings?

Comment: `I want to end up whith this form of url domain.com/(image-slug)`.¿From what? ¿How is the URL in the browser's address bar that should be mapped as `domain.com/(image-slug)`? Or is it the other way around: You want `domain.com/(image-slug)` to be mapped silently to `domain.com/(article)/image-(image-slug)`.

Comment: You can't just change the urls with mod_rewrite. You'll have to change WP (too), as WP parses the urls. Just changing the urls in htaccess would make WP unable to "recognize" the url, and spit out the correct page.

Answer (score 0):

Please view this article from another user who had a similar problem, which they solved using PHP inside there .htacess.

[.htaccess shorten URL using php $_GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9649636/htaccess-shorten-url-using-php-get)